# Counting bits over each position in multiple files

Tags: python, file, loops

```
for z in range(1,n+1):
    with open("file_{}.bin".format(z), "rb") as file:
        for byte in file:
            for bit in byte: 
                if bit=='0':
                    s0+=1
                else:
                    s1+=1 
        break
```

I used the break to stop the loop `for byte in file:` to read the same position on the next file and increment it but it returns just for one loop

I want to count number of 0 for every single position on multiple files, 
Example :

file_0.bin contains

```
10110000
```

file_1.bin contains

```
11101010
```

The output for position 0 will be : 0

The output for position 1 will be : 1

.

.

The output for position 7 will be : 2

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Fix your indentation first, please.

Comment: Edited, just a mistake when I copied it :)

Comment: Do all files have the same sized bytes?

Comment: Yes they have the same size

Comment: Furthermore, do the files contain binary data or simply bit strings?

Comment: Just bit strings, they can also be written in a .txt files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `collections.Counter`, its purpose is meant for just this - acting as a counter. You can use `enumerate` to keep track of indices as you increment.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for z in range(1, n + 1):
    with open("file_{}.bin".format(z), "r") as file:
        for byte in file:
            for i, bit in enumerate(byte.strip()):
                c[i] += (1 - int(bit))

print(c)
```

This results in a cleaner approach than storing multiple variables in memory.

---

If you only have one bytestring in your file, the solution simplifies a bit:

```
with open("file_{}.bin".format(z), "r") as file:
    byte = file.read().strip()
    for i, bit in enumerate(byte):
        c[i] += (1 - int(bit))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't know how to count bits which value equal "0" for position 0 of all the files at the same time, this code works just to count in one file?

Comment: @amintou Okay, my bad. This code was counting all the 1s, not all the 0s. Changed that now.

Comment: All my files have 9307 Bytes, I just need to loop over single position and count the '0' for each files, it looks complicated but your codes seems to work

Comment: They are in a single line, example: 
file_01.bin contains 01010101010101000001010010100001.....